# Nexe compile error, missing files? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used this command to package a js script into a portable package using Nexe.

nexe -i ./compressed.js -o ./compiledcode

but after waiting over an hour for it do a bunch of things, it packaged  it all up, but when I start the compiledcode file, I get this error.

```
compiledjs ozziepeck$ ./compiledcode
bootstrap_node.js:393
throw new Error(`No such native module ${id}`);
^

Error: No such native module ./charset.js
at NativeModule.require (bootstrap_node.js:393:13)
at s (nexe.js:1:176)
at nexe.js:1:367
at nexe.js:22625:16
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.__dirname.88 (nexe.js:22623:18)
at s (nexe.js:1:316)
at nexe.js:1:367
at Object.__dirname.84.mime-types (nexe.js:16004:18)
at s (nexe.js:1:316)
```